# What may cause raised lines on drywall?

Tags: walls

We are noticing some puffed up lines on the wall not sure what it is. I see these lines in 2 places staircase and dining hall (high ceiling) going all the way to adjacent wall not visible in dining hall pic . I attached images. Do you know what they are  and what causes them ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know the exact makeup of these walls? They look like seams between drywall panels

Answer (score 3):

Those are almost certainly seams between sheets of drywall that are either settling or have suffered moisture damage. (By far the most likely is settling, but since there's a window above, I wouldn't rule out moisture.)

Check the exterior and interior on the window above to see if there's any evidence of leakage.

Otherwise, you could re-tape, texture, and paint, but that's a lot of time for not a lot of benefit.

Comment: I agree that it is a tape seam +. this can also happen when there are large temp swings. I have seen several "Snow Bird" homes have much worse problems when they turned there heat down to ~60 or off while they were gone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont see any sign of moisture. I would post some more pics soon.